# KIE execution server Indictment API

Tags: drools, optaplanner, kie, drools-planner

There is an API for java to get IndictmentMap from Optaplanner core ScoreDirector interface. But I am not directly using Optaplanner engine but using KIE server instead that solves my planning problems. Is there an API to get indictment from solver?

Basic Optaplanner API is provided [here](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.1.0.Final/optaplanner-wb-es-docs/html_single/#_optaplanner_rest_api).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**kie-server 7.2 does not support this yet.** [Vote for this issue.](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-872)